# Adding Rubymine features to Jetbrains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea

Forgive me as I am new to the ruby environment, in fact I do most my developing in other languages. As such I would love to use intellij as I understand it can do everything all of it's sibling IDE's can. That be said I have looked through the plugins and can't seem to find anything that is related to Ruby/Rubymine. Can someone please tell me which modules I need to enable and where I might find those so I can spin up a ruby project?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To use Ruby plugin functionality in Intellij you need to install this plugin:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1293.

The differences between RubyMine and Ruby plugin are listed here

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1146

Key point is

> The Ruby plugin for IntelliJ IDEA is built from the same codebase as RubyMine. Some features may be temporary not available in the plugin because the latest available IntelliJ IDEA bases on an earlier IntelliJ platform compared to RubyMine.